# Website displays differently on iPhone compared to Chrome simulation

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, frontend

Could anyone help me figure out why my calculator isn't displaying correctly on iPhones specifically? I've used a reset sheet and it looks fine in my Chrome simulation and on my Android device.

Also tested both Chrome and Safari on the iPhone.

Here's the website:
https://zainiscoding.github.io/calculator-project/

And the source code:
https://github.com/zainiscoding/calculator-project

And here's what it looks like on iPhone:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YrCe.png

Comment: which iphone sir? i don't see any problem on iphone 5/6/7/8/X. or not even on my android phone.

Comment: All iPhones. Are you sure? I've tested it on different iPhones and emulators since you made that comment, and it still looks off. See the picture I posted in the OP to see what I mean.